# Node.js console application

Tags: node.js

Привет.

Недавно решил попробовать node.js и написать простое консольное приложение. Суть проста: я хочу нажимать на стрелки на клавиатуре, и хотел бы какую-нибудь реакцию от приложения (например, вывод слов left, right). Для меня основной сложностью стало отсутствие синхронных методов обработки или событий с возможностью не завершаться основному потоку программы.

Я несколько вечеров изучал эту тему, но ничего, кроме примеров легковесных веб-серверов, не нашел. Возможно ли это вообще сделать?
У меня нет опыта в работе с подобными вещами. Дайте какие-нибудь советы или рекомендации.

Answer (score 4):

Вы хотите сделать node-приложение с "псевдографическим" интерфейсом (как FAR)? Посмотрите библиотеку [`blessed`](https://github.com/chjj/blessed):

[image: Jitsu]

Comment: Спасибо за библиотеку. Но я бы не особо хотел использовать что то готовое. Мне просто интересно узнать как пишутся подобные вещи в контексте node.js. А читать код библиотеки, к сожалению, у меня не хватает пока компетенции.

Answer (score 1):

[RTFM](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin), как говорится.

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
  process.stdout.write('end');
});
```

Comment: @deivan, Спасибо, но это обработчик на символьный ввод, который должен завершаться нажатием enter. Этот мануал я читал, у меня несколько другая проблема.